# Perl/MySQL: last_insert_id returns 0

Tags: mysql, perl, dbd-mysql, dbix-connector

`last_insert_id` returns for the newly inserted row.

Everything is working just fine with Perl 5.18.

From the forums I understand that it might be because of some loosing connection. But can't see anything in the trace.

Here is the code sample:

```
  $self->_dbx->query(q{DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_tbl;});

  $self->_dbx->query(q{
    CREATE TABLE user_tbl(
      user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      user_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY ( user_id )
    );
  });

  $self->_dbx->query(q{
    INSERT INTO user_tbl 
              (user_name)
      VALUES  ('DUMMY1');
  });

  print Dumper $self->_dbx->last_insert_id(undef, undef, undef, "user_id" ) or warn "Warn: Can not get it?";

  print Dumper $self->_dbx->query(q{
    SELECT * FROM user_tbl
      WHERE user_name= 'DUMMY1';
  })->hash;
```

DBI_TRACE:

```
    <- ping= ( 1 ) [1 items] at Driver.pm line 28
    <- prepare('
    CREATE TABLE user_tbl(
      user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      user_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY ( user_id )
    );
  ')= ( DBI::st=HASH(0x70f4468) ) [1 items] at Simple.pm line 168
    <- execute= ( '0E0' ) [1 items] at Simple.pm line 187
    <- finish= ( 1 ) [1 items] at Simple.pm line 286
    <- FETCH('Active')= ( 1 ) [1 items] at Connector.pm line 129
    <- FETCH('Active')= ( 1 ) [1 items] at Connector.pm line 129
    <- ping= ( 1 ) [1 items] at Driver.pm line 28
    <- prepare('
    INSERT INTO user_tbl 
              (user_name)
      VALUES  ('DUMMY1');
  ')= ( DBI::st=HASH(0x70f47c8) ) [1 items] at Simple.pm line 168
    <- execute= ( 1 ) [1 items] at Simple.pm line 187
    <- finish= ( 1 ) [1 items] at Simple.pm line 286
    <- FETCH('Active')= ( 1 ) [1 items] at Connector.pm line 129
    <- FETCH('Active')= ( 1 ) [1 items] at Connector.pm line 129
    <- ping= ( 1 ) [1 items] at Driver.pm line 28
    <- last_insert_id(undef, undef, ...)= ( '0' ) [1 items] at Simple.pm line 216
```

STDOUT:

```
$VAR1 = '0';
$VAR1 = {
          'user_id' => 1,
          'user_name' => 'DUMMY1'
        };
```

Versions:

- Perl => 5.22
- DBD::mysql => 4.043
- MySQL Server 5.6

Comment: What does `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`  return?

Comment: it correctly returned the new id.

Comment: With `DBD::MySQL` the `last_insert_id` has to be called immediately after the insert. I guess that the `DBIx::Connector`, which you seem to be using, inserts the `ping` call after it, so that the call doesn't follow insert immediately. Try without `DBIx::Connector` and see if it works.